# При нажатии RadioButton - disable всех нужных CheckBox = true

Tags: java, javafx, checkbox, radiobutton

Постановка: требуется при нажатии на рад.кнопку, если она включена - все чек боксы нужные для работы (Не все чекбоксы на сцене, только часть) стали активными, т.е. disable=false.
При повторном нажатии получаем обратный результат, все боксы становятся неактивными.

Сейчас это реализовано так:

```
radioButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(radioButton.isSelected()){
                CHB1.setDisable(false);
                CHB2.setDisable(false);
                CHB3.setDisable(false);

            }
            else{
                CHB1.setDisable(true);
                CHB2.setDisable(true);
                CHB3.setDisable(true);
            }
        });
```

Но бесконечно добавлять новые 2 строчки на 1 чекбокс не катит.
Прошу помощи, как боксы можно привязать к рад.кнопке

PS.все элементы вынесены в переменные

```
    @FXML
    private CheckBox CHB1;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox CHB2;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox CHB3;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton RB;
```

Comment: Так сделайте список, который будет привязан к радиокнопке и проходясь по нему меняйте состояние чекбокса - это очень неплохо вынесется в отдельный метод и можно будет переиспользоваться для каждой радиокнопке передавая ее и связанный список.  list.forEach(it -> it.setDisable(!radioButton.isSelected()))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сделал почти то же самое, только прикрепил не к кнопке а к VBox, дабы удобнее расположение элементов было.